# Unique GUID across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on an ETL process in which we move data from several staging tables to their corresponding destination tables (with some transformation).

This process involves a parent stored proc, which call child procs, 1 proc for each table.

We have a log table in which has a GUID field as a primary key. This GUID should remain the same for all of the records which were updated/inserted in the corresponding ETL process.

Currently, I do the following:

```
DECLARE @etlid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC dbo.etl_premier_main @etlid
        EXEC dbo.etl_premier_financial @etlid
```

We simply declared a GUID in parent procedure and passed it as a parameter to child procedures.

However, this method does not ensure that every time it will generate a unique value for the log table.

Comment: *"However, this method does not ensure that every time it will generate a unique value for the log table. "* That's exactly what `NEWID()` does. An Instance will not reuse a `uniqueindentifier` it has already created.

Comment: The documentation even says that SQL Server uses `uniqueidentifier` to achieve this: *"Merge replication and transactional replication with updating subscriptions use uniqueidentifier columns to **guarantee that rows are uniquely identified across multiple copies of the table**.*"

Comment: @Larnu Thanks. I assumed that NEWID() generates unique values only for the current context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try switching to `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`.

> Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated by this function on a specified computer since Windows was started.

There are some considerations I would read the following Microsoft [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
DECLARE @etlid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWSEQUENTIALID() BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC dbo.etl_premier_main @etlid
        EXEC dbo.etl_premier_financial @etlid
```

Comment: Considering @Larnu 's remarks, I guess the current method would not cause any problems. Thanks for the response.

Comment: This will only be of benefit if the OP has a Clustered Index on the column, as the pages won't need to be be reordered after every insert, if not `NEWID` serves the same purpose here.